# Prove that the function in $[0,\pi]$ defined by $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ and $f(0)=1$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f$ be a function $f:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$f(x)=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{\sin(x)}{x}  & \mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
  1 & \mbox{if } x = 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
I want to prove that $f$ is a contraction, i.e., $\exists\alpha\in(0,1)\forall x,y\in[0,\pi]:\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\leq\alpha\lvert x-y\rvert$

I wanted to prove that $f'(x)=\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$ attains a minimum in $(0,\pi)$ which is greater than $-1$, hence $\lvert f'\rvert$ has a maximum $\alpha=\lvert f'(m)\rvert\in(0,1)$. Finally by the M.V.T for all $x,y\in[0,\pi]$ there'd be a $c\in(x,y)$ such that 
$$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert=\lvert f'(c)\rvert\lvert x-y\rvert\leq\lvert f'(m)\rvert\lvert x-y\rvert=\alpha\lvert x-y\rvert$$
However when studying the second derivative of $f$, I got to a point where $m$ must satisfy the equation $(2-m^2)\sin(m)=2m\cos(m)$ and from here I have not figured out a way to get what I want.

So can you give me a hint on how to proceed? or if there's an easier way to prove that $f$ is a contraction, can you give an outline of the proof? (Thanks in advance).

Comment: Consider the behavior of $g(x)=\sin x-x$ on $[0,\pi ]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\cos x - \sin x = \int_0^x (\cos x -\cos t)\, dt = \int_0^x \int_t^x (-\sin s)\,ds\, dt.$$

Crash through with absolute values to see the above, in absolute value, is less than

$$\int_0^x \int_t^x 1\,ds\, dt = \int_0^x (x-t)\,dt = x^2/2.$$

Divide by $x^2$ and we get $|f'(x)| \le 1/2$ everywhere on $\mathbb {R}.$ That leads to the desired solution.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Just out of curiosity, how did you come up with this? Is it a common trick?

Comment: Or what led you to use integrals?

Comment: I noticed in the past that showing $(x-\sin x)/x^3 \to 1/6$ could be obtained without Taylor (or L'Hopital) if we grant the FTC: $x-\sin x = \int_0^x(1-\cos t)\,dt,$ etc. So sometimes it seems like this is a good way to go.